# Google vision api integration in java (error)

Tags: java, api, typeerror, google-vision

I am trying to implement and add google vision services to my project using the below github sample code link. 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/text/
Running into this error in ImageText and Word java classes where

```
public static Builder builder() {
return new AutoValue_ImageText.Builder();
  }
```

where AutoValue_ImageText type can not be resolved and

```
 public static Builder builder() {
return new AutoValue_Word.Builder();
  }
```

where AutoValue_Word type cannot be resolved.
please help! i can not even fix these syntax errors to see if this code even complies properly.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that the gradle file is missing there. 
Make shure you have that line inside your app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.0.0+'
}
```

For me, this little walkthrough helped me a lot: [Mobile Vision Text](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#0)

Comment: i am using maven, is there an equivalent dependency i may add to my pom.xml? thank you